# How do I truncate performance_schema tables on a read replica?

Tags: mysql, performance, aurora, read-only-database

On occasion, you have to truncate events_statements_summary_by_digest, when it's hit the row limit. On a write master, this is easy, but on a read replica, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. The read-only enforcement extends to the performance_schema tables. Since the data are created locally, it seems to me that there'd be a way that I could exempt those tables (or even the entire performance_schema DB) from the read-only enforcement?

I have already set the performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size to 10000, which is getting pretty large. I could set it larger (well, if it weren't read-only), but the size of that table affects overall system performance, and I'd rather not just crank the limit to something obscene - especially when so many of the entries in the history haven't been used in a mont or two. It's better to toss out the garbage.

Comment: To turn it off, see: [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-system-variables.html#sysvar_performance_schema), and [stackoverflow: What does MySQL's performance_schema do and what are the ramifications of disabling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337059/what-does-mysqls-performance-schema-do-and-what-are-the-ramifications-of-disabl#:~:text=By%20far%20the%20most%20common,cnf%20.)

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the Slave as `root` (or other `SUPER` user) bypasses `readonly`, thereby allowing you to do that 'truncate'.

(Caveat: this Answer is theoretical; I have not tested it.)